# matlab live video extraction

Tags: matlab, video-capture

How do you take a live video feed from a webcam and selectively extract frames of it? Do I need a special toolbox or can this be done through normal matlab functions?

I have the image acquisition toolbox, but haven't seen a good way to use it for this yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image acquisition toolbox is all you need. Just look at the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.de/help/toolbox/imaq/f9-75080.html) and it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure that the webcam is properly installed and connected.
2. type the following code:

   ```
   obj = videoinput('winvideo', 1);
   preview(obj)
   ```

this shall generate a window capturing live video input.